# Convert a Source to Flow in Scala

Tags: scala, akka-stream

How to convert a Source to Flow?

Input: Source[ByteString,NotUsed] a
Intermediary Step: Call an API which returns an InputStream
Output: Flow[ByteString,ByteString,NotUsed]

I am doing it as:
Type of input is = Source[ByteString,NotUsed]

```
val sink: Sink[ByteString,InputStream] = StreamConverters.asInputStream() 
val output: InputStream = <API CALL>    
val mySource: Source[ByteString,Future[IOResult]] = StreamConverters.fromInputStream(() => output)
val myFlow: Flow[ByteString,ByteString,NotUsed] = Flow.fromSinkAndSource(sink,source)
```

When I use the above Flow in the source it returns an empty result. Can someone help me figure out of I am doing it right?

Comment: `fromSinkAndSource` is for very specific use case, have you read it's documentation https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/operators/Flow/fromSinkAndSource.html?

Comment: Can you explain what's the purpose of converting a source to a flow? A source produces elements, a flow transform one element into something else.

Comment: My API returns a Flow to the consumers(cannot change the underlying api) and there is another API call which is made which retunrns an InputStream. I am converting the inputstream to a Source and trying to return a Flow using that Source. There may be elegant way to do that but I am unaware of that. @Gael J

Comment: A flow receive elements as input. Assuming you're a le to write a flow, what would it do to the input elements? And would that relate to the Input stream you're mentioning? It feels like you want to make a square fit in a circle.

Comment: My input is Source[ByteString,NotUsed] which should be an input to the FLow which is then fed to another API which returns an inputstream and converted to ByteString in the flow. Not sure if I answer your question but I am not able to change the underlying API which takes a Source and returns a Flow.  I know this may not be elegant design but this is actually a temp workaround which I am trying to figure out.

Comment: This is what I came up with so far:https://scastie.scala-lang.org/UFOOga13QxuBvBNvddnmjg

Comment: Do you need to consume the inputstream one by one? If so I'd go with https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/operators/Source-or-Flow/flatMapConcat.html. Let me know if this answers your need and I can make it a proper answer.

Comment: Thanks @GaëlJ, like you mentioned earlier, #sinkAndSource is not the correct one to use since we have inputs to the flow at runtime. I tried flatMapConcat and use nested maps to get InputStream and converted it to ByteString. Looks like the solution you mentioned is working. I still need to write some unit tests to verify but I am marking your solution as answer to this since I am able to create a Flow using the Source I have. Thanks for looking into this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure tu fully grasp what you want to achieve but maybe this is a use case for `flatMapConcat`:

```scala
def readInputstream(bs: ByteString): Source[ByteString, Future[IOResult]] =
  // Get some IS from the ByteString
  StreamConverters.fromInputStream(() => ???)

val myFlow: Flow[ByteString, ByteString, NotUsed] = 
  Flow.flatMapConcat(bs => readInputstream(bs))

// And use it like this:
val source: Source[ByteString] = ???
source
  .via(myFlow)
  .to(???)
```